# From Flex/MXML and XAML to HTML. What are the best options?

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, xaml, mxml, ria

I know Flex MXML / AS3 very well. I also have good knowledge in C#,XAML and ASP.NET.

I will be forced in the next years to do more HTML (Webapps) work. I could take ASP.NET but i dont like it really as i have to care about all that browser specific things and coding Javascript ist just horrible when you come from C# and AS3. Also ASP.NET isnt just as smooth in writing and using Components as it is in MXML or XAML. MXML (with FDT not FlashBuilder) and XAML also have awesome tooling for their Markuplanguage and their business language which i need.

I know some Java too and willing to learn a new language if gives me what i need.

I took a look at Vaadin and GWT but both seem to lack a Markuplanguage. Beeing Searchengine friendly would also be a big plus. Any Recommendations ?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the HTML 5.0 standards going forward and the admission of Adobe that they'll be dropping support for Flex you might want to look at ASP.Net

Also remember that Microsoft is going to stop doing Silverlight stuff

It's not what you want to hear, but it's an option you may have to pursue.

Comment: I know that Adobe and MS will lower the effort in Flash and Silverlight even so i think Flash/SL are 4-6 years ahead of HTML 5. Thats why i am forced to go HTML more and more. I do ASP.NET already i just can not enjoy it and be as productiv as i am with Flex/MXML or XAML...

Comment: It is incomplete to say that Adobe will not be dropping support for Flex.  They are turning Flex over to an open source foundation (Apache).  They'll have a team (dozens of people) still committed to the Flex SDK.  The Flash Builder team remains unchanged.  This comes out of today's Flex Summit that Adobe is live streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:

- [Haxe](http://haxe.org/blog/)
- [OpenLaszlo](http://openlaszlo.sourceforge.net/)
- [Laszlo White Paper](http://www.openlaszlo.org/images/LaszloWhitePaper.pdf)
- [Breaking OpenLaszlo loose from XML data](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364149/Breaking-OpenLaszlo-loose-from-XML-data)
- [The Server-side Architecture Behind OpenLaszlo Applications (pdf)](http://www.uwyn.com/resources/serverside_architecture_behind_openlaszlo_apps.pdf)
- [SWF Scout SDK](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/swfscoutsdk/swfscout.html)
- [Swiff Chart Generator](http://www.globfx.com/products/swfchartgen/)
- [Tour de Flex](http://flex.apache.org/tourdeflex/index.html)
- [OpenLaszlo Whitepaper](http://www.openlaszlo.org/images/LaszloWhitePaper.pdf)
- [SVG-Based User Interface Framework](http://www.svgopen.org/2004/papers/SPARK/)